# How to load Visualforce page fast?

Tags: javascript, ajax, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Here i am loading Visualforce page from href using Jquery Tab. now when i click on that Tab page is loading Good but all links are disable for few seconds. it takes a time to full load a page. here i m providing my code. So please suggest me how can i load that page fast ??? and one more thing i would like to ask is i want to put loading image still page is loading and when total page is loaded then after loading image should be disable.

```
<div class="demo">
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/apex/page1?id=001A000000iTVx9">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="/apex/page2?id=001A000000iTVx9">Transaction</a></li>
      <li><a href="/apex/page3?id=001A000000iTVx9" >Dispute</a></li>
      <li><a href="/apex/page4?id=001A000000iTVx9" >Notes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When pasting code, be sure to indent [one tab or four spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), otherwise it won't render as code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `cache="true"` in the `<apex:page>` tags, but if I recall correctly this is `true` by default. The thing is for each page there's a lot of extra javascript files to load etc., and I suspect those get pulled down each time by the plugin you're using.

If you put standard pages into tabs are they any faster? If not, I'd say there's not much you can do, if so, then maybe it's something specific to your pages.

Comment: Thanks Laceysnr , In my first page there is no any java script function or any java script file. And I had put Standard page also. But It is not solving this issue. Please suggest me any solution. Is there any java sciprt to write to solve it ????

Comment: Sounds like you're out of luck I'm afraid :( Is there any option in the jQuery tabs plugin to pre-load the tab contents (i.e. load up the other pages while the first one is displayed)?

Comment: ok. i think it is good idea. other else there is no idea. can you tell me how to implement this thing if you know ????